# Layout functionality doesn't work after layout params changes

Tags: android, layout

In my app, I'm implementing `onConfigurationChanged` , in which I'm repositioning by buttons and `imageView` to match the new configuration.

After the change to landscape mode, the buttons does not work, I mean, no `onClickListener` is working.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    System.out.println("changed!");
    if ( PackageBuilder.popupW!=null )
        if ( PackageBuilder.popupW.isShowing() ) {
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageviewp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) (PackageBuilder.popUpView.findViewById(R.id.mImageView)).getLayoutParams();
                imageviewp.topMargin=(int)( (screenHeight) / (4.15) );               
                imageviewp.height=(int)((screenHeight)*(0.25)); //250
                imageviewp.width=(int)((screenWidth)*(0.3125)); //200

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams a=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) (PackageBuilder.popUpView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewR)).getLayoutParams();
                a.height=(int)((screenHeight)*(0.25));
                a.width=(int)((screenWidth)*(0.3125));
            }

            else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageviewp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) (PackageBuilder.popUpView.findViewById(R.id.mImageView)).getLayoutParams();
                imageviewp.topMargin=(int)( (screenHeight) / (2) );
                imageviewp.height=( (int) ( (screenHeight)*(0.15)) ); //120
                imageviewp.width=( (int) ( (screenWidth)*(0.145)) );  //70

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams a=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) (PackageBuilder.popUpView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewR)).getLayoutParams();
                a.height=( (int) ( (screenHeight)*(0.15)) );
                a.width=( (int) ( (screenWidth)*(0.145)) );
            }
        }
}
```

Notice that I'm not changing the content view, I'm simply getting the references to the layout widgets and changing thier layout params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to handle runtime changes on my own and had the same problem.

From the developer's site:

> Note: Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications.

In order to let the system handles the change for you and just change the layout of things, create a **layout-land** folder inside your **res** folder and just put the new .xml file with the same name as it's in **layout** folder. So, when your orientation change to landscape, it'll look for the xml inside your layout-land folder.

Comment: Should I use android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" in the menifest? should I implement onConfigurationChanged in order for this to work?

Comment: No, you shouldn't use the android:configChanges and neather implement onConfigurationChanged. Take out both of them and just put the new layout inside layout-land. In portrait, the xml inside the layout folder will load, and in landscape, the xml inside layout-land instead.